# Showing that for a projection-valued measure $\pi$ the function $\langle\pi(E)u,v\rangle$ is a complex measure

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, orthogonality

Let $\pi$ be a **projection-valued measure** as defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection-valued_measure).

Prove: For every $u,v \in \mathcal{H}$ and $E \in \mathcal{M}$ the function
$$ \mu_{u,v}(E):= \langle\pi(E)u,v\rangle $$
defines a complex measure.

---

I'm struggling to show that for every disjoint $E_1,E_2,...$ in $\mathcal{M}$ the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu_{u,v}(E_n)$ converges absolutely, that is:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty |\langle\pi(E_n)u,v\rangle|<\infty$$

Since $E_1,E_2,...$ are disjoint, $\pi(E_n)$ are orthogonal projections and $\pi(E_n \cap E_m)=\pi(E_n)\pi(E_m)$, one can show that:
$$\forall m \neq n, \forall u,v \in \mathcal{H}:$$ $$\langle\pi(E_n)u,\pi(E_m)v\rangle=0$$
So I thought using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, or a similar proof to Bessel's inequality, but I can't see how to use the fact that $\pi(E_n)u$ and $\pi(E_m)v$ are orthogonal.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with summable families or commutatively/unconditonally convergent series?

Comment: Not sure, can you please elaborate?

Comment: A series of elements of an ablelian topological group is said to be commutatively convergent if it remains convergent when you arbitrarily rearrange its terms. Very interestingly, it can be shown that a commutatively convergent series of complex numbers is always absolutely convergent.

Comment: Didn't know that, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space.

Consider the polarisation identity (which can be proven by simply expanding the right hand side):
Let $S: H \times H \to \mathbb{C}$ be sesquilinear.
Then for all $x,y \in H$:
\begin{align*}
        4 S( x, y) 
         &=  S(x+y, , x+y ) \\
          &- S(x-y , x-y ) \\
          &+ i S(x+iy, x+iy ) \\
          &- i S(x-iy, x-iy ).
\end{align*}

Now for fixed $E \in \mathcal{M}$ the map $(x,y) \mapsto \langle \pi(E) x, y\rangle = \mu_{x,y}(E) $ is sesquilinear.
This means that if we can show that $\mu_{x,x}$ is a complex measure (we will actually show that it is a finite non-negative measure) for every $x \in H$, we obtain that $\mu_{x,y}$ is a measure for all $x,y \in H$ from the polarisation identity, because the sum of complex measures is a complex measure again.

Let $x \in H$ arbitrary.

For every $E \in \mathcal{M}$:
$$
\mu_{x,x}(E) = \langle \pi(E) x, x \rangle = \langle \pi(E) x, \pi(E) x \rangle = \| \pi(E) x \|^2 \leq  \| x\|^2,
$$
because $\pi(E)$ is an orthogonal projection. This shows that $\mu_{x,x}$ is non-negative and finite. Clearly $\mu_{x,x}( \varnothing) =0$.
And if $\cup_{n=1}^\infty E_i$ is the disjoint union of measurable sets, then
$$
\mu_{x,x}(\cup_{n=1}^\infty E_i) 
= \langle  \pi (\cup_{n=1}^\infty E_i ) x ,x \rangle
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \langle  \pi(E_i) x, x\rangle
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu_{x,x}(E_i),
$$
because the scalar product is continuous and the definition of a projection valued measure.
This shows that $\mu_{x,x}$ is a finite non-negative measure, which ends the proof.

Comment: That's very helpful, thanks a lot!